# JLabel not displaying image on screen

Tags: java, jlabel, imageicon

so for a project of mine I have to draw graphics to the screen using `JLabel` and `ImageIcon`. I've done some research but I just can't seem to get it to render anything to the window. It should render 20 birds each with different locations however the screen remains blank. Here is the class file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

class Graphics
{
    public static final String SIMULATOR_NAME = "Flocking Simulator 2K16";
    public static final int MAXIMUM_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int MAXIMUM_HEIGHT = 780;

    static Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public Graphics()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(SIMULATOR_NAME);
        frame.setSize(MAXIMUM_WIDTH, MAXIMUM_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(canvas);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        canvas.clear();
    }

    public void DrawBirds(Flock birds, String graphic)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < birds.GetMaximumBirds(); i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("Bird#" + i + "\n");
            Bird b = birds.GetBird(i);
            frame.add(BirdGraphic(b, graphic));
        }
    }

    public JLabel BirdGraphic(Bird bird, String graphic)
    {
        System.out.printf(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + graphic + "\n");
        ImageIcon birdImage = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + graphic);
        JLabel birdLabel = new JLabel(birdImage);
        CartesianCoordinate loc = bird.GetPosition();
        birdLabel.setLocation((int)Math.floor(loc.getX() + 0.5), (int)Math.floor(loc.getY() + 0.5));
        return birdLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + graphic).exists()` returns `true` .

Comment: Just checked it returns `true`

Comment: How is the frame called? I don't see anything added to it besides `frame.add(canvas);` ? Please also provide the main method launching your application.

Comment: The main application method just calls this line: `GFX = new Graphics();` which then runs the constructor class of Graphics.

Comment: So your `DrawBirds` method is never called.

Comment: Whoops, Its called in the game loop in that function too.

Answer (score 0):

You must not add the labels directly in the frame. You must add them to some panel which must the in the frame. We also don't know what you really want to do, what is the purpose of your Canvas?
Also don't mix awt and swing, I mean don't use `Canvas`, prefer `JComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've now tried doing this myself but just can't seem to get it to work, care to give an example of how I can add labels to a panel and then translate it onto a frame? I'm kinda getting lost at this point sorry.

Comment: You didn't gave us sufficient information: where do you want your labels to appear? What is your canvas for? More code...